# Sorting while using specific culture - "BB" may come first before "AA" in Danish and Norwegian

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, .net-4.0

Today I noticed an interesting sorting behavior in C#. I have two lists and I sort them:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
list1.Sort();
list2.Sort();
```

The two lists now contain:

```
>> list1
[0]: "A"
[1]: "B"
[2]: "C"

>> list2
[0]: "BB"
[1]: "CC"
[2]: "AA"
```

Why is the AA put in the end?

Here is a demonstration: http://ideone.com/QCeUjx

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aahrus#Aarhus.2F.C3.85rhus_spelling

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that since I am using Danish culture settings, .NET assumes that "AA" is the Danish letter "Å" which is at the end of the Danish alphabet.

Setting the locale to `en-US` gives me the sort order I expected ("AA", "BB", "CC").

[This article](http://www.siao2.com/2006/04/27/584439.aspx) has some background information.

Comment: I should also point out that I probably *do* want to sort "AA" as "Å" since the application is in fact targeted for a Danish platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the overload of [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) to ignore the current culture. [`Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal.aspx)  performs a simple byte comparison that is independent of the current  language:

`list1.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);`

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://ideone.com/j0E6kz)</kbd>

Here are some informations: [Normalization and Sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230117%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Some Unicode characters have multiple equivalent binary
>   representations consisting of sets of combining and/or composite
>   Unicode characters. Consequently, two strings can look identical but
>   actually consist of different characters. The existence of multiple
>   representations for a single character complicates sorting operations.
>   The solution to this problem is to normalize each string, then **use an
>   ordinal comparison to sort the strings**....

Comment: Oh yeah, I had totally forgot about the `StringComparer` parameter. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can change that current locale setting use following code line.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "BB", "AA", "CC" };

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

list1.Sort();
list2.Sort();
```

Comment: Instead of changing the current thread's culture it is better to pass `StringComparer.Ordinal` to `list1.Sort`.

Comment: @Leez that is exactly what I found out while I was writing the question which is the reason I choose to answer it myself in the end. I couldn't find similar questions on SO so hopefully someone will be directed this way in the future if they have a similar question.